# Magento2 custom extension and PWA support

Tags: javascript, magento2, progressive-web-apps, graphql-js

Here’s my question about PWA and custom Magento 2 extensions.
I am a Magento backend developer, and I have a dim idea of PWA frontend implementation. I’ve been developing a Magento SEO extension and try to add some compatibility for PWA. I assume that on the backend side, it is an extension's Graph QL API. The SEO extension changes info in different sections of a page - head section (meta title, meta description, canonical URL, microdata in json-ld format, etc.), content section - modified product/category name, or description, modified breadcrumbs. I want to ask frontend developers about using graph-ql calls.
Please, mark the better solution in your opinion:

1. Extension extends and/or changes the default Magento graph-ql answers. For example, the modified product description will come to the front.
2. The extension has its own graph ql controller(s) and you force to add additional call(s) for getting SEO data for the whole page.

Note, in case #1, the following situation is possible: you already have the head section of a page, and now you call the product information and receive the regular product data and in addition, the canonical URL, which must be placed in the head section.
Is it a problem to use data from one graph-ql query to modify a previous section based on the previous graph ql?

If you’ve ever used custom extensions for PWA, I would highly appreciate any info or best practices to study. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I have built a PWA extension for Magento 2, you can see detail at http://pwablog-m2.com/

Or you can get some demos:

http://pwablog-m2.com/blog

or https://pwablog-m2.com/blog

or https://pwablog-m2.com/demo03/

or https://pwablog-m2.com/demo02/

or https://pwablog-m2.com/demo04/

Comment: People upvote if they find it useful. No need to request for it.